# Inserting data using a sub query and a standard value

Tags: sql

I am trying to insert data into a table using a sub query. I want to select the data I need based on the where clause and then insert this into the table. However the PlaylistID isn't part of the tblTrack table and I want to input this as a value which I set but within the same SQL Query. How would I go about doing this? Sorry this may be a simply answer, I am relatively new to using SQL.

```
INSERT INTO tblPlaylist_Tracks (TrackID, ArtistID, AlbumID, PlaylistID) VALUES 
(SELECT TrackID, ArtistID, AlbumID
FROM tblTrack
WHERE Track_Name = "Pacifier", 7);
```

Comment: Please add your DBMS

Answer (score 1):

this is the correct syntax:

```
 INSERT INTO tblPlaylist_Tracks (TrackID, ArtistID, AlbumID, PlaylistID) 
 SELECT TrackID, ArtistID, AlbumID,7
 FROM tblTrack
 WHERE Track_Name = 'Pacifier'
```

Comment: PlaylistID is probably an integer column. I.e. no need to pass the integer value 7 as as character string.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, was about to show the difference between a normal insert and one with a subquery to OP and i forgot to clean.